# Where should I hook into admin?

Tags: admin, hooks, headers

Where should I hook into the admin backend to check and see if the user is "active" as defined by the Membership Plugin.

Or in other words, where can I hook into the WP admin header to check an if-statement and redirect if it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Membership plug-in bit, but [`admin_init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) will be your best bet. I assume that you don't actually what to hook into the admin header though - this would be [`admin_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head) or [`admin_head-(plugin_page)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head-%28plugin_page%29) - but you cannot redirect after these hooks (headers already sent).

Comment: admin_init is it!